# How long and at what temperature do the various parts of a chicken need to be cooked?

Tags: baking, chicken, cooking-time

I'm interested in baking thighs, legs, breasts and wings.  How long do each of these items need to bake and at what temperature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ochef.com](http://www.ochef.com/418.htm) answered this question.
Here are some quotes from the webpage.

> According to the USDA:
>
> Round chicken/turkey: 165°F / 74°C
>   Whole chicken/turkey: 180°F / 82°C
>   Poultry breasts, roasts: 170°F / 77°C
>
> Additionally, the USDA says the thighs
>   and wings of poultry should be cooked
>   "until the juices run clear."

Although the following temperatures will make the meat safe to eat, you might want to drop the temperature by 3-5°C for more flavor.

Answer (score 3):

I do thigh, wings, and drumsticks to 180F (82C) and breasts to 170F (77C).